# One-to-many mappings in one entity in EF First code

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have 2 classes :

```
public class GroupType
{
    [Key]
    public decimal GroupTypeID   { get; set; }
    public string  Title         { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public decimal          GroupID          { get; set; }
    public string           Title            { get; set; }
    public decimal?         GroupParentID    { get; set; }
    public decimal          GroupTypeID      { get; set; }
    public string           FileName         { get; set; }
    public string           GroupCode        { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupType> GroupTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> MainGroups { get; set; }
}
```

when I debug project, I get this error:

> "Invalid column name 'GroupGroupID'.
>   "**  and  **Navigation property
>   'MainGroups' of
>   'Parand.DataAccess.Group' cannot be
>   the inverse of itself.

I want define tree of Group (**n** layers of groups)

How can I do that it?

Comment: are you using Entity Framework CTP 5.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

This will create the self referencing association in the `Group` entity:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
                .HasMany(g => g.MainGroups)
                .WithOptional()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.GroupParentID);
}
```

The many to many association between `Group` and `GroupType` will be created using a join table so you should remove `GroupTypeID` property from the `Group` entity since it will be treated merely as a scalar property and not a Foreign key for this association.